# Can objects be (de)serialized in richfaces xhtml?

Tags: xhtml, serialization, jsf, xml-serialization, richfaces

Can Richfaces (de)serialize objects? Say for instance, I have a row of data being displayed in a richfaces table. Can I serialize the row of data to a string and later deserialize it back into a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to turn a JSON object into a string in javascript. The following link contains a good tutorial on JSON:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize anything on the server-side - i.e. in a managed bean.

Then you can output it wherever you want with `#{yourBean.yourSerializedJson}` (or iterate over a collection of serialized data).